# Why my Samsung laptop keeps going off

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card

> Windows 7 Professional Service pack 1 Processor- Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU - M380 @2.53Ghz 2.53Ghz RAM - 2.00GB System type - 64bit OS NVIDIA Version 341.44 GeForce GT 330M DirectX runtime version: 11.0

Once in a while my laptop keeps going off, I'm suspecting it's because of the graphic card but I don't have the allowance to go get another one. My brother told me it's the RAM, but he too is not sure.

**Is there anything else that could cause this and what can I do to fix it?**

Comment: Did you check the eventlogs in System ?

Comment: First guess for a sudden total power-down would be overheat or under-power [they both give similar symptoms]. When was it last stripped & cleaned?

Comment: The day the OS was installed was when it all started

Comment: @GiaRui How do I check the eventlogs and how can that affect the shutting down of my laptop

Comment: It dosen't affect your computer to shut down, however you might see what happened at that time. Go to start and type eventvwr.msc and look for system at the time the shutdown happenend. Perhaps an error or warning must be showed.